# Laravel Vue Fullcalendar more Tabels

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar

I use the Fullcalendar in my school project and take the code from this Video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_WMkIKztRQ). 
The Calendar works but i dont get more than one Table to fill the calendar.

**My Component Code:**

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <Fullcalendar
        @eventClick="showEvent"
        @select="handleSelect"
        :plugins="calendarPlugins"
        :header="{
        left: 'title',
        center: 'dayGridMonth, timeGridWeek, listWeek',
        right: 'prev today next'
        }"
        :buttonText="{
        today: 'Heute',
        month: 'Monat',
        week: 'Woche',
        list: 'Liste'
        }"
        :events="EVENTS"
        :weekends="true"
        :selectable="true"
        :firstDay="1"
        locale="de"
        setAllDay= "true"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Fullcalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import TimeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import ListPlugin from "@fullcalendar/list";
import deLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/de';
import axios from "axios";
Vue.use(axios);
import FullCalendar from 'vue-full-calendar';
Vue.use(FullCalendar);


export default {
  components: {
    Fullcalendar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      calendarPlugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, TimeGridPlugin, ListPlugin],
      EVENTS: "",
      newEvent: {
        event_name: "",
        start_date: "",
        end_date: "",

      },
      addingMode: true,
      indexToUpdate: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getEvents();
  },
  methods: {
    handleSelect(arg) {
      console.log(arg)

    },
    addNewEvent() {
      axios
        .post("/api/calendar", {
          ...this.newEvent
        })
        .then(data => {
          this.getEvents(); // update our list of events
          this.resetForm(); // clear newEvent properties (e.g. title, start_date and end_date)
        })
        .catch(err =>
          console.log("Unable to add new event!", err.response.data)
        );
    },
    showEvent(arg) {
      this.addingMode = false;
      const { id, title, start, end, day } = this.events.find(
        event => event.id === +arg.event.id
      );
      this.indexToUpdate = id;
      this.newEvent = {
        event_name: title,
        start_date: start,
        end_date: end,
        allDay: true
      };
    },
    updateEvent() {
      axios
        .put("/api/calendar/" + this.indexToUpdate, {
          ...this.newEvent
        })
        .then(resp => {
          this.resetForm();
          this.getEvents();
          this.addingMode = !this.addingMode;
        })
        .catch(err =>
          console.log("Unable to update event!", err.response.data)
        );
    },
    deleteEvent() {
      axios
        .delete("/api/calendar/" + this.indexToUpdate)
        .then(resp => {
          this.resetForm();
          this.getEvents();
          this.addingMode = !this.addingMode;
        })
        .catch(err =>
          console.log("Unable to delete event!", err.response.data)
        );
    },
    getEvents() {
      axios
        .get("/api/calendar")
        .then(resp => (this.EVENTS = resp.data.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data));
    },
    resetForm() {
      Object.keys(this.newEvent).forEach(key => {
        return (this.newEvent[key] = "");
      });
    }
  },
  watch: {
    indexToUpdate() {
      return this.indexToUpdate;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="css">
@import "~@fullcalendar/core/main.css";
@import "~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
.fc-title {
  color: #fff;
}
.fc-title:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

**My App JS:**

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */


require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('calendar-component', require('./components/CalendarComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('calendar-component1', require('./components/CalendarComponent1.vue').default);
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));


/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */
window.onload = function () {
// const app = new Vue({
//
//
//     el: '#app',
// });
}
const app = new Vue({
    state: {
    events: []
  },
  getters: {
    EVENTS: state => state.events
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_EVENT: (state, event) => {
      state.events.push(event)
    }
  },
  actions: {}
}).$mount('#app')
```

**My Controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\CalendarResource;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\up_calendar;
use App\up_request;
use App\Calendar;
use DB;

class CalendarController extends Controller

{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
      return CalendarResource::collection(Calendar::all());

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $new_calendar = Calendar::create($request->all());
        return response()->json([
            'data' => new CalendarResource($new_calendar),
            'message' => 'Successfully added new event!',
            'status' => Response::HTTP_CREATED
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Calendar  $calendar
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Calendar $calendar)
    {
        return response($calendar, Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Calendar  $calendar
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Calendar $calendar)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Calendar  $calendar
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Calendar $calendar)
    {
        $calendar->update($request->all());
        return response()->json([
            'data' => new CalendarResource($calendar),
            'message' => 'Successfully updated event!',
            'status' => Response::HTTP_ACCEPTED
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Calendar  $calendar
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Calendar $calendar)
    {
        $calendar->delete();
        return response('Event removed successfully!', Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

**Ressource:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CalendarResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
      return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'title' => $this->event_name,
        'start' => $this->start_date,
        'days' => $this->calendar_holyday,
        'end' => $this->end_date
      ];


    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class up_calendar extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

I Get only the events from one table. And i have no Idea how to get more in the same Calendar.

Just want events and reqeusts in the same table highlighted with different colors.

Hope someone can help me.

I would be very grateful

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but I wonder if https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources would help you.

Comment: Ty for ur comment. Sorry for my bad english i m from german.

Answer (score -1):

Ty for ur comment. Sorry for my bad english i m from german.
The eventSources look exactly like what i m looking for. I tried to use it but if i implement it i got an error from VUE

*ERROR in ./resources/js/components/CalendarComponent2.vue?vue&type=script&lang=j s& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--4-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue
-loader-options!./resources/js/components/CalendarComponent2.vue?vue&type=script &lang=js&)*

This is the CalendarComponent2.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <Fullcalendar
        :event-sources="eventSources"
        :weekends="true"
        :selectable="true"
        :firstDay="1"
        locale="de"
        setAllDay= "true"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Fullcalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import TimeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import ListPlugin from "@fullcalendar/list";
import deLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/de';
import axios from "axios";
Vue.use(axios);
import FullCalendar from 'vue-full-calendar';
Vue.use(FullCalendar);


export default{
data() {
return {
  calendarPlugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, TimeGridPlugin, ListPlugin],
  eventSources: [
    {
      events(start_date, end_date, event_name, callback) {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/events').then(response => {
          callback(response.data.calendardata)
        })
      },
      color: 'yellow',
      textColor: 'black',
    }
  ]
}
}
};
```

Comment: Surely it should be `:eventSources` instead of `:event-sources`

Comment: I also get an error
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <Fullcalendar> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <CalendarComponent2> at resources/js/components/CalendarComponent2.vue
       <Root>

Without the eventSource he know <Fullcalendar>